# What is the relation between hilb and Hilbert transform in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, hilbert-transform

In MATLAB, there is a command called `hilb(n)` which it says gives a Hilbert matrix of order `n`.  Is this matrix the one used for Hilbert transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) has nothing to do with the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), other than that both are named after the famous German mathematician [David Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hilbert).

Comment: Thanks Matt L for the clarification.  I also did not see any relation and your answer confirmed my opinion.  But I doubted if David Hilbert has anything to do with the two different things especially the Hilbert matrix.

Comment: @SeethaRamaRaju: He does (as with lots of other things). Read the article I linked to.

Comment: L:  Thank you.  I saw the links now, clear now why MATLAB named them the way it did.  Thanks for your full answers.

Comment: I would love to know of a connection. You can check the unanswered question [Hilbert transform and Hilbert matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260059/hilbert-transform-and-hilbert-matrix)